# clear d3js elements update the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, svg, d3.js

I used d3.js to display some data from a external json file on a webpage. To keep the data updated i added the setInterval() function. The problem is that i need to delete the previous svg elements first to update the data. Ho can i do this? Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
                d3.json("data.json", function (data) 
                {
                    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", "100%")
                        .attr("height", 800);

                    var text = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
                        .data(data[0].Bodenfeuchtigkeit)
                        .enter()
                        .append("text");

                    var textLabels = text
                        .attr("x", "15%")
                        .attr("y", 475)                 
                        .attr("font-family", "Open Sans, sans-serif")
                        .attr("font-size", 75)
                        .attr("fill", "green")
                        .text(data[0].Bodenfeuchtigkeit + " %");

                    var text1 = svgContainer.selectAll("text1")
                        .data(data[0].Luftfeuchtigkeit)
                        .enter()
                        .append("text");

                    var text1Labels = text1
                        .attr("x", "45%")
                        .attr("y", 475)
                        .attr("font-family", "Open Sans, sans-serif")
                        .attr("font-size", 75)
                        .attr("fill", "green")
                        .text(data[0].Luftfeuchtigkeit + " %");

                    var text2 = svgContainer.selectAll("text2")
                        .data(data[0].Temperatur)
                        .enter()
                        .append("text");

                    var text2Labels = text2
                        .attr("x", "75%")
                        .attr("y", 475)
                        .attr("font-family", "Open Sans, sans-serif")
                        .attr("font-size", 75)
                        .attr("fill", "green")
                        .text(data[0].Temperatur + " \u00B0C");
                })
            }, 3000);
```

Comment: `d3.selectAll("svg").remove()`

Comment: Thank you! But what would be a elegant way to include this in my code because i tried it with another setInterval function inside the previous function, but its not working very well!

Comment: Run it just before you append the new SVG. Note that the D3 way is to update the existing visualisation, not just redraw it. There are lots of tutorials on this on the D3 website.